# search forms with html and js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lookup page for customers to search insurance contracts. A dropdown lets them select whether they want to search by name (first and last), vin #, or date range.

```
               <div class="formbar">
                    <div class="formslot">
                        <label for="which">Search by</label>
                        <select id="which" name="which" onchange="javascript:selected();">
                            <option selected="selected" value="name">Find By Name</option>
                            <option value="vin">Find By VIN</option>
                            <option value="recent">Recent Business</option>  
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Each option has it's own form and the `selected()` function just formats the current form and hides the others. Pressing search triggers this function

```
    $("#search").click(function (event)
    {
        var chosen = $("#which").val();
        alert("''" + chosen + "''");
        if (chosen == "name") {
            var ln = $("#lastname").val().trim();
            var fn = $("#firstname").val().trim();
            alert(ln + " " + fn);
            if (ln.length < 2 && fn.length < 2) {
                alert("Either first or last name must contain at least two characters.");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        } else if (chosen == "vin") {
            var vinend = $("#vinend").val();
            alert(vinend);
            if (vinend.length < 6) {
                alert("At least six characters are required.");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        } else if (chosen == "recent") {
            var before = $("#before").val();
            var after = $("#after").val();
            alert("before: " + before + " after: " + after);
            var first = moment(after, "YYYY-MM-DD");
            var last = moment(before, "YYYY-MM-DD");
            var delta = Math.floor(((last - first) + 86399999) / 86400000);

            if (delta > 30) {
                if (!confirm("You have requested " + delta + " days of data.\n" +
                        "This may take quite a long time.\n\n" +
                        "Continue with these dates?")) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The only time the `alert("''" + chosen + "''");` works is when name is selected and the other alerts don't go off when recent business or vin are selected and I can't figure out why. Any ideas on what might be happening here?

example of one of the forms:

```
           <section id="form.name">
                <form id="agreements" name="agreements" action="${request.uri}" method="post" class="form">
                    <div class="formslot">
                        <label for="first">First Name</label>&nbsp;
                        <input type="input" id="firstname" name="first" value="${search.first}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="formslot">
                        <label for="last">Last Name</label>&nbsp;
                        <input type="input" id="lastname" name="last" value="${search.last}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="formslot">
                        <input type="submit" class="roundbutton" name="search" id="search" value="Search" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>
```

Comment: could you also add the html for the `#search` button? I think the `selected` method might be causing a problem, or the html for the search button might be getting deleted

Comment: I added one of the forms for reference

Comment: I think each of your form has the search button with the same id. you have to make them unique, like `#searchByName` etc. ALTERNATIVELY, you can just use one buttton and place it out of the forms. That one button can handle the all three form submissions

Comment: MY HERO. Thank you

Comment: I posted it as an answer with a small snippet, plz accept it if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search buttons for the three forms have the same id `#search`. You should use only one search button and place it out of the three forms, that way you wouldn't have to change much in the js file.

OR

You can assign the different search buttons a unique id like, `#searchByName`, `#searchByVim` and `#searchByRecent`, and in the js you would just have to do

```
$("#searchByName, #searchByVim, #searchByRecent").click(function (event)
{
...
}
```

Please confirm first if this is valid in jquery